# What soviet telescope is this?

Tags: telescope, telescope-lens, identify-this-object

A friend has a vintage telescope with a broken lens, I asked him to send me its catalog so I can see if I can buy him a new one, he gave me what looks like a Russian catalog, it seems a soviet telescope, I can't read it, I hope you could tell me what it is. I want to search for its lens using English characters.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible search terms to use:

- Vintage Russian CCCP Spotting Scope 3PT-460 20x
- Komz Russian Military Telescope - 3PT-460 20x
- ZRT 460 Russian Scope

Images of item:

[image: Picture of 3PT-460 - Image 1]

[image: Picture of 3PT-460 - Image 2]

[image: Picture of 3PT-460 - Image 3]

Prices I found range from \$50 to less than \$100.

Comment: Yes you are correct I've seen it, it's white and resembles the ones in your picture, possibly the last, I'll show you a picture when I can. The lens costs that much right  not the telescope? Do you know a specific website I could buy lenses or Amazon and ebay are my only friends? Because those two don't have just lenses.

Comment: The 50-100 is the cost for what is shown in the above images, my *point* being that repair may not be practical unless you can find a lens for 10 bucks. I saw them on EBay and used telescope dealers in Europe. I suspect that they are such low cost that people only advertise a complete working unit in good to excellent condition in order to make a sale of a significant amount. Likely some place somewhere has the bits and pieces that they used to fix another one to sell a working unit. Try searching for the minimum text "3PT-460" and "scope" along with "used" or "2nd hand". Many I saw are *new*.

Comment: What is the range of such telescopes? like when you read 3pt-460 20x how does that convert to range? Because I found many newer telescopes in my country but I don't know if they can see further or not than the original. Sellers here say range between 1 and 2 km

Comment: It depends on the size of the object you are looking at. Basically the object will appear 20x closer or larger. So an object 200m away will look like it's 10m away, a person at 200m will look like a person standing 10m away (you'd be able to identify them, whereas at 200m away you probably couldn't; unless you knew them). At 2000m (2 km) you could see a tank (which is what they are for) but you certainly couldn't read a book that appeared to be 100m away.

Comment: I added the picture in the question, it's like the ones in the answer

Answer (score 3):

Pervomaisk Machine-Building Plant. Portable tripod. Price: 4 rubles 20 kopecks.
Portable tripod is designed for lightweight movie cameras and cameras for various kinds of shooting.

Spotting scope. Model ZRT-460. 
Characteristics: https://market.yandex.ru/product--zritelnaia-truba-komz-zrt-460/7084940/spec